# Adding Color attribute option in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1, product, adminhtml, attributes

How can I add extra Color attribute options ( blue, black , etc) which are not already show in Magento admin when adding configureable / simple products..

I did it a few months ago, it was some database hack, involved two tables I think so and that was by following a tutorial.

Can anyone suggest an improved way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the backend, in the main menu to

- *catalog > attributes > manage attributes*
- search for the color attribute and click on it.
- Go to **Manage label / options** and add your new color options there.

Comment: yes..adding color names to standard dropdown list which holds colors

Comment: If you go to the backend, in the main menu to 'catalog' > 'attributes' > 'manage attributes', search for the color attribute and click on it. Go to 'Manage label / options' and add your new color options there.